# Recurring problems in Dart polymer project

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-editor

I am having a problem that seems to be due to caching of dart packages etc.

My work machine runs some dart polymer examples without any problem. I use the same project on my home machine it it consistently gives the exception below:

Exception: Class '_textfieldElementExtension' has no instance method 'createInstance'.

```
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'createInstance'
Receiver: Instance of '_textfieldElementExtension@0x1d7f4e'
Arguments: [Instance of 'MyExample', Instance of 'PolymerExpressions']
PolymerElement.instanceTemplate (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:383:30)
PolymerElement.shadowFromTemplate (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:233:31)
PolymerElement.parseDeclaration (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:202:34)
PolymerElement.parseDeclarations (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:194:23)
PolymerElement.prepareElement (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:170:22)
PolymerElement.created (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:152:21)
_initCustomElement (package:custom_element/custom_element.dart:622:18)
registerCustomElement (package:custom_element/custom_element.dart:62:25)
```

I know that DartEditor places file .dartium and DartEditor in the users directory. Apart from these directory and the installation directory of the editor itself, where else are DartEditor files placed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a directory where the downloaded packages are stored. (`~/.pub-cache` for linux, don't know Windows).